# Increase CMIS result limit from 100 to 1000

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

We are using **Alfresco** as a repository and querying it using **Apache CMIS api**.

We use below code to connect it.

```
parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/cmis/versions/1.1/atom?maxItems=1000");
```

Querying alfresco...

```
OperationContext opCon = session.createOperationContext();
opCon.setLoadSecondaryTypeProperties(true);
opCon.setMaxItemsPerPage(1000);
session.query(queryStr);
```

But the CMIS always returns 100 records only. But when I use standalone **CMIS workbench** program and give the above URL to connect to Alfresco with **maxItems=1000**, it returns **1000** records.

**The *maxItems* parameter is not working when I use my JAVA CMIS api.**

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I got it working...

While querying to Alfresco, I was not passing the OperationContext where I set the page size.

```
OperationContext opCon = session.createOperationContext();
opCon.setLoadSecondaryTypeProperties(true);
opCon.setMaxItemsPerPage(1000);
session.query(queryStr, false);  // wrong....
session.query(queryStr, false, opCon);  // right
```

Now when I iterate to the **ItemIterable**, I am getting more than 100 results.

Thanks to everyone for their time and help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get around this issue.

https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-20766?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I will also try to put this in Alfresco forums.....

Comment: Just to make things clear, there's nothing Alfresco configuration related that can be done; it depends on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new operation context, you can use the default context to configure a session. The following will work as expected.

```
session.getDefaultContext().setMaxItemsPerPage(1000);
session.query(queryStr);
```